# UITextView Cursor Moves When Editing Begins

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextfield, uistoryboard

When a user taps into my `UITextField` the field clears and the cursor moves up outside of the bounds of the **TextField**. The issue corrects itself once the user has entered a letter, but will recur every time the field clears on edit.

The **TextField** was created in a storyboard and nothing was done programmatically, auto layout is also turned off on the storyboard. Any ideas?

Also, the cursor moves down instead of up if the user had entered text, leaves and returns to the app.

I should note that this doesn't happen in simulator, only on actual hardware.

Thanks in advance for any ideas anyone has.

EDIT:  Unfortunately my low reputation won't allow me to post screenshots.

EDIT 2:

After doing some research on the topic, I've found my problem is two-fold:

1. The cursor is actually just shrinking when editing begins and the field clears.  Playing around with content alignment in IB I was able to figure that out.
2. If the app is closed out of during editing and reopened the cursor and text move downward, outside of the visible area of the TextField.

Comment: what about the delegates? an image will be more explanatory

Comment: Hi Lithu, I have the viewcontroller set as the delegate, but I'm not configuring the textfield in any way aside from color from the delegate.  Here's a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/KamnfGA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know what I was doing wrong, but after playing with things a bit longer, I removed and recreated my label and the issue resolved, so I must have messed something up in IB that was causing that behavior, as I didn't change anything else.